# Community login with pre-filled username for OAuth 2 authentication

Tags: community, oauth2, login, username

According to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5) it is possible to pass a `login_hint` to the OAuth 2 login endpoint (which is the community URL in this case) as long as the `prompt` is also passed, set to "login":

> IMPORTANT To pass the login_hint parameter for Communities, also pass the prompt=login parameter. Together, these parameters redirect the user to the login page with the correct login hint.

However, this doesn't seem to be working for me. I have tried this with both ARC (the Advanced REST Client chrome app) and by manually constructing the OAuth 2 URL of the form:

```
https://the-community-host.force.com/the-community-url-path?response_type=token&
  client_id=3MVxxxxxxxxxxTheOAuthConnectedAppClientIdxxxxxxxxx&
  redirect_uri=https://the-agreed-callback/url&
  scope=api&
  login_hint=the@user.name&
  prompt=login
```

(NB: I've also tried URL encoding the "@" in the username but this makes no difference.)

Both approaches result in the login page like:

[image: Community Login Page no Login Hint]

Note how the URL only includes `ec=302` (one presumes this is indicating a 302 redirect is required to the endpoint callback) and `startURL=%2Fthe-community-url-path%2Fs%2F` which seems to cover where the access should eventually end up (the community home page).

Do you know how to get a standard Community login page to include the login_hint as a pre-entered username?

Comment: I've taken your advice and raised a support case. Let's see if they take it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

The URL to use for this authentication login as part of the OAuth 2 flow is in fact one like:

```
https://the-community-url/services/oauth2/authorize?
  redirect_uri=https://the-agreed-callback/url&
  login_hint=the@user.name&
  prompt=login
```

Additional query parameters, such as scope, can be included as needed (it seems this automatically includes the scopes for which the community was configured if not defined). Using this will successfully leverage the login hint, pre-populating the username.

**ORIGINAL**:

After discussion with Salesforce Support, it appears that the URL for community login should be explicitly including the login path segment, thus:

```
https://the-community-host.force.com/the-community-url-path/login?response_type=token&
  client_id=3MVxxxxxxxxxxTheOAuthConnectedAppClientIdxxxxxxxxx&
  redirect_uri=https://the-agreed-callback/url&
  scope=api&
  login_hint=the@user.name&
  prompt=login
```

Doing this experimentally did appear to work.